# Qual componente devo usar?

Tags: c#, mysql, devexpress

Estou criando um sistema, e existe um parecido com o meu, na tabela da imagem, eu irei criar uma lista, onde possuirá um check, um label, 2 textedit e uma imagem para indicar q o check esta marcado.. Entao.. qual componente devo usar? Já procurei em tupo e nao achei um q se encaixe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então User Control não é técnica de programação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adolfo Moro, não tenho certeza se é isso, mas uma vez eu fiz uma "lista de controles". Eu tenho um exemplo, mas está em VB6 e só tem uma TextBox na qual eu adicionei várias novas propriedades para ela.

### ACTIVEX CONTROL TEXTBOX - USER CONTROL

Um controle "herdado" do TextBox que restringe Texto permitindo só números se for configurado em Properties, gerencia se recebeu foco por cores e faz outras propriedades e um evento personalizado.

http://www.vbmania.com.br/index.php?modulo=detalhe&id=9445

---

O que você pode fazer é criar um "User Control" seu adicionando todos os componentes que você criou e mandar chamá-lo toda vez que precisar de mais uma linha. Abaixo um exemplo em C# do Macoratti.

### C# - Criando Controles Personalizados (User Control)

Neste artigo veremos como podemos criar controles personalizadas na linguagem C#.

Quando você está desenvolvendo o seu programa Window Forms, o designer do formulário é onde você organiza seus controles e decide qual a aparência deseja dar a eles. Existe também um designer para controles de usuário, o User Control Designer, que permite que você decida como será o controle de usuário.

http://www.macoratti.net/17/07/cshp_control1.htm

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu queria!!! Dei uma pesquisada, coloquei um TableLayoutPanel e gerei UsersControls dentro dele, e ficou simplismente perfeito!!!

Comment: #adolfo-moro, obrigado por me pontuar.